# systemd-timedated.service: Failed to determine whether NTP is enabled: Link has been severed

Tags: systemd, ntp, time, time-synchronization, chrony

Encountering this issue with RHEL 7.9 (Maipo).

One server in particular is having issues with `timedatectl`, `systemd-timedated.service`, and `chrony`.

If we run `timedatectl`

```
$ timedatectl 
Failed to query server: Connection timed out
```

Further, if we attempt to start `systemd-timedated.service`

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-timedated.service
● systemd-timedated.service - Time & Date Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timedated.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-30 20:43:40 CEST; 1min 33s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timedated.service(8)
           man:localtime(5)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated
  Process: 59236 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-timedated (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 59236 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 30 20:43:40 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Sep 30 20:43:40 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Sep 30 20:43:40 HOSTNAME systemd-timedated[59236]: Failed to determine whether NTP is enabled: Link has been severed
Sep 30 20:43:40 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 30 20:43:40 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: Unit systemd-timedated.service entered failed state.
Sep 30 20:43:40 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service failed.
```

Would anyone happen to know the root cause of this `Link has been severed` error message and a possible solution?

```
Failed to determine whether NTP is enabled: Link has been severed
```

Answer (score 0):

It took a ticket with corporate IT, who forwarded the issue to Red Hat, to find out that there was an erroneous file on the system.

```
sudo mv /etc/systemd/system/chronyd.{service,wrong}
```

resolved the problem.